# What tech to use to build a very basic hotel booking type web-app?

Tags: java

I'm a newbie.  :( 
I've taken about 4 Java courses and written some simple apps.  As part of a class, I wrote a order purchasing application with JDBC  and JSP pages/servlets.  The bummer about all this is that there wasn't much info in the class on using eclipse & such and it seems there are more efficient and modern ways of doing this now.

I want to keep learning and since my ski club has a need to streamline it's booking process (currently email), I thought I would see if I could write an application to do this.   I think the right way to do this would be to write something that could support a webservices type interface, so I could eventually (maybe I'm getting ahead of myself) write a mobile app as well.   I'm getting a bit confused by all the choices out there though as I don't understand well how the different layers fit together and what the best place is to start.   So, to summarize: 
1) Beginner level Java - would like to continue using it.
2) Want to build a simple hotel booking type app.
3) Would like a webservices (SOAP?) like interface to the front end
4) Open-source tools
FWIW: I'll be doing this on a macbook but could also do a linux VM.  I also have my own hosted domain and mysql db I could setup there for testing.

I'd like it if someone could recommend an approach for me.  Perhaps some tutorials or an online class that would get me closer to getting started?  Pretend you are me.  :) 
Thanks!

Comment: BE HAPPY. say - I'm a newbie. :-)  :-)  :-)  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your plan seems pretty good.

I think this makes sense.

- MySQL if you want to use a SQL DB
- JSP/Servlets for the front-end; probably only JSP
- JDBC and Hibernate for accessing the DB (unless you want to use a NoSQL DB like e.g. MongoDB); maybe only Hibernate really as you don't want to mess with the low-level JDBC API
- [MongoDB Java driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/) if you want to use MongoDB instead of a SQL DB
- Tomcat to run your JSPs
- I would suggest RESTful web services over SOAP web services, if you really need to use web services; REST is easier to implement and more lightweight

I guess that would be sufficient.

Comment: I've heard of Hibernate as well.  Does the Spring framework mentioned below include Hibernate or is that just another piece?

Comment: Hibernate is different from Spring. It is a framework used in persistence layer. Hibernate can be plugged with Spring to manage all the persistence and fetching of the data from database. If you need features like text search in your website, you can use Lucene search engine library, which can be plugged with hibernate.

Answer (score 2):

Use Spring ROO. It is good for an entry-level website and it doesn't required in-depth knowledge of all technologies enlisted. As you learn more you can replace components with your own.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/

Comment: Sounds interesting. +1

Comment: This sounds good and interesting.  I think I'm torn between your suggestion and hellboy's below.  I just need to look.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest -

UI - JSP, HTML , CSS
 Database - You said you already have MySQL, which should be good for your use case.
 Java Framework - Spring framework. This will give you out of the box support for rest service. Using spring will help you adhere to some good design principles without having to know them. As a newbie I would highly recommend to go with spring. I am not a big fan of SOAP. Unless that is imposed as a constraint I would not recommend SOAP.

Reference that could be helpful - http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/

Comment: This step-by-step guide looks good.  I've heard of spring as well.  I'm going to take a look at this and see.  Will update everyone once I get farther along.